# get day wise average task time in python

Tags: python, pandas

Friends in the dataframe I have

```
ID      creationdateTime     Totaltime
283318  2018-03-30 18:54:18  64.7000
283316  2018-03-30 18:50:35  87.4000
283249  2018-03-30 17:55:51  114.9333
283213  2018-03-30 17:34:54  107.8500
283197  2018-03-30 16:25:15  71.8000
283178  2018-03-30 15:13:10  140.5500
283171  2018-03-30 10:09:18  108.1833
283154  2018-03-30 08:59:11  116.1333
```

etc.

The list will give for 1 yr day wise data for all IDs.

which model i can use to get the trend? How i can get the average time taken for completing a task(3rd column values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understand correctly, you have a data of second or minute wise and you want to compute the average for day. 
First of all you have to combine the `creationdateTime` time column day wise which can be done with Grouper functionality and then you can use the mean function so that it will get you the mean in 3rd column for every entry on that day.

```
daywisedf = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='creationdateTime',freq='1d')).mean()
```

This will get average of each day in 3rd column itself.

Note: Your `creationdateTime` should be in datetime format in order to use Grouper.

For more info visit Pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html

Answer (score 0):

make `creationdateTime` as index.

```
df.set_index('creationdateTime', inplace=True)
```

then,

```
df['2018-03-30 18'].Totaltime.mean()
df['2018-03-30'].Totaltime.mean()
df['2018-03'].Totaltime.mean()
df.resample('D', kind='period').mean()  # more `rule`, please check `help(df.resample)`
```

show trends:

```
df.Totaltime.plot()
```